# Is b in the span of {w_1, .. , w_p}?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose **b** is in the span of { **v_1** , ... , **v_n** }, and that each **v_i** is in the span of { **w_1**, ... , **w_p** }. Is **b**, then, in the span of { **w_1**, ... , **w_p** } ? If not, how could you modify the proposition so that it is true?

Not sure at all how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

If $b$ is in the span of $\{v_1, \dots, v_n \}$, then

$$b = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i,\tag{1}$$

for some $\alpha_i$. Similarly, if each $v_i$ is in the span of $\{w_1, \dots, w_p\}$, then

$$v_i = \sum_{j=1}^p \beta_{ij} w_j,\tag{2}$$

for some $\beta_{ij}$. Now, substitute $v_i$ in $(1)$ with what you have in $(2)$. Now, is $b$ in the span of $\{w_1, \dots, w_p\}$?

Answer (score 0):

$b\in \text{span}\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$

$v_i\in \text{span}\{w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_n\}$, i.e., $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}\subset \text{span}\{w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_n\}$ and hence $\text{span}\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}\subset \text{span}\{w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_n\}$.

So $b\in \text{span}\{w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_n\}$.

Hi, Brian. You'd better read your textbooks carefully before doing homework. We learn mathematics by understanding definitions, theorems and properties instead of thinking all by ourselves. Good luck.

Comment: What I was unsure about was the move from **v_i** to implying the whole set {**v_1** , **v_2**, ... , **v_n** }. In fact, I am still unsure about it. **v_i** seems to refer to the ith vector, which is only one vector. Yet you move from **v_i** = span { w_1, ... , w_p } to  {v1,v2,⋯,vn}⊂span{w1,w2,⋯,wn}. Still trying to see how the transition is made.